# Can't type letter Z on laptop keyboard and arrow keys don't work

Tags: keyboard

I have a Toshiba laptop running Windows 7.

For some reason I'm unable to type the letter <kbd>Z</kbd> or use any of the arrow keys. If I insert an external keyboard then it works fine.

What is wrong? How can I fix my laptop keyboard?

Comment: The keyboard is broken.  Most likely due to something spilled on it.  Sometimes you can disassemble things and wash the keyboard to recover from this (I did a long post on this topic maybe a year back), but the odds are against it.

Answer (score 3):

It could be that your laptop keyboard is broken, if an external keyboard is working okay.
Are the <kbd>z</kbd> and arrow keys feeling okay when you press them?
If they don't feel good you can be sure it is broken.

Changing a laptop keyboard is quite expensive, unless you have insurance.

Comment: Yes, for the external keyboard it respond well. The problem is on the laptop keyboard only.

Comment: Did you wet the keyboard with coffee or something? Maybe somebody did and didn't tell you...

Comment: Your laptop's keyboard is dead buddy. Take it to the service for change keyboard..

Comment: Thans for all, I will check all posibility before taking decionn of buying new one.